# How to disable default message: "Your request processed successfully"?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How would I disable this default message: "Your request processed successfully" for my plugin portlet when an add/update action is performed in my portlet?

Also I would want to disable this for my custom configuration page (`configuration.jsp`), this is the configuration page which is shown when we click on the wrench icon which appears on the top-right corner of every portlet.

Is there a configuration option anywhere which I can set or some code which I can write to disable it?

Or else would it be possible to change the message from my custom portlet and `ConfigurationActionImpl`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. This message can be disabled for all actions in my portlet through the following configuration in `portlet.xml`:

   ```xml
   <init-param>
       <name>add-process-action-success-action</name>
       <value>false</value>
   </init-param>
   ```
2. Alternatively it can also be changed for a particular action rather than for all actions:

   ```java
   public void addEmployee(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

       // ... all the code processing

       String successMsg = "Employee added Successfully!";

       SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "request_processed", successMsg);
   }
   ```

Thanks to the information present in this [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5872211).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is there a analogy to error msg for the key "request_processed"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Liferay DXP 7.1 and for me worked the following in Action Command:

`SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, PortalUtil.getPortletId(actionRequest) + SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_HIDE_DEFAULT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);`